# Error crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated - When trying to access the shopee website with .ee domain that is affiliated

Tags: web, browser, shopee

when trying to access a normal shopee website, with the .ee domain, which means to be an affiliate referral product, I get the error "crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated", this only occurs on my virtual ubuntu machine , I can't find any solutions, can anyone help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoFat.jpg)

site: https://shope.ee/6KW52L7cQ5

I want to be able to access the site normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it turns out that my virtual box machine network was configured for NAT just changed it to Bridge, for that go in the VM settings -> Network -> Connected to -> Bridge

[image]